# prove that there is $c \in (a,b)$ (about calculus)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Statement**

1. $f$ is not a constant function.
2. $f'$ is continuous, differentiable in $(a, b)$.
3. $f(a)=f(b)=0$
4. $n\in\mathbb{R}$

**Prove it**

There is $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that $f'(c)+nf(c)=0$.

I used the Rolle's theorem to prove it, but I didn't prove. Because of $+nf(c)$.

+Please do not use DE.

Comment: Does $f'$ extend to a continuous function on $[a,\,b]$?

Comment: What is DE? And what does condition (4) mean? That the claim's true for *any* real n?

Comment: @Landscape, I *almost* got that when I read your comment. Make that an aswer...or I will. :) +1

Comment: @DonAntonio 1. DE is the differential equation.  2. Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(t) = e^{nt}f(t)$. Then $g$ is continuously differentiable inside $(a,b)$ with
$$g'(t) = e^{nt}f'(t) + ne^{nt}f(t) = e^{nt}(f'(t) + nf(t)).$$
Moreover, $g$ also satisfies $g(a) = g(b) = 0$ so by Rolle's Theorem there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$g'(c) = e^{nc}(f'(c) + nf(c))= 0.$$
Dividing by $e^{nc}$ we have
$$f'(c) + nf(c) = 0.$$

Comment: @CrMT In fact, the construction of $g$ is essentially related to the theory of ordinary differential equations. It's a basic trick called *integrating factor*. You can search it online. Anyway, learning something deeper is seldom harmful.